# Compare two files and extract line based on matching substring?

Tags: regex, bash, file, hash, text-processing

I have two files

crackedHashes.txt formatted as Hash:Password

```
C3B9FE4E0751FC204C29183910DB9EB4:fretful
CA022093C4BAFA397FAC5FB2E407FCA9:remarkable
36E13152AA93A7631608CD9DD753BD2A:please
```

hashList.txt formatted as Username:Hash

```
Frank:C3B9FE4E0751FC204C29183910DB9EB4
Jane:A67BC194586C11FD2F6672DE631A28E0
Lisa:CA022093C4BAFA397FAC5FB2E407FCA9
John:36E13152AA93A7631608CD9DD753BD2A
Dave:6606866DB8B0232B371C2C4C35B37D01
```

I want a new file that combines the two lists based on the same matching hash.

output.txt

```
Frank:C3B9FE4E0751FC204C29183910DB9EB4:fretful
Lisa:CA022093C4BAFA397FAC5FB2E407FCA9:remarkable
John:36E13152AA93A7631608CD9DD753BD2A:please
```

I've been scouring the forums here and can only find things returning one string or not using regex (matching whole line). I've tried to do it in parts so I first broke up crackedHashes by doing `sed 's/:.*//'  crackedHashes.txt` and then was going to do the same for the other file and compare by basically writting a bunch of outfiles and comparing the outfiles. I also tried comparing based on variation of `grep -f crackedHashes.txt hashList.txt > outfile.txt` but that was yielding many more "results" than it was supposed to.

I could manually do `grep <hash> hashList.txt>` but when it comes to files and lines I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU join, bash and GNU sort:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -t : <(sort crackedHashes.txt) <(sort -t : -k 2 hashList.txt) -o 2.1,1.1,1.2
```

Output:

```
John:36E13152AA93A7631608CD9DD753BD2A:please
Frank:C3B9FE4E0751FC204C29183910DB9EB4:fretful
Lisa:CA022093C4BAFA397FAC5FB2E407FCA9:remarkable
```

---

See: `man join`

Comment: Unfortunately nothing's returning for me. Wouldn't `sort` not work because on one list its sorting by hash and the other it's sorting by username?

Comment: Use it once: `dos2unix crackedHashes.txt hashList.txt`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much, you have no idea how much this helped!

Comment: or use this: `join -1 1 -2 2 -t : <(dos2unix <crackedHashes.txt | sort) <(dos2unix <hashList.txt | sort -t : -k 2) -o 2.1,1.1,1.2`